# App keeps force closing

Tags: android

I have created a simple app that allows the user to type a phone number into a box, then press a button which starts an activity that searches the contacts and returns the contact name that matches the phone number entered.

However the app keeps force closing.

Here is the code

```
package com.xenom.text;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.PhoneLookup;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class DriveAndTextActivity extends Activity 
{

private View button1;
private String Text1;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 


    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        private String TAG;

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "mbutton1 clicked");
            Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(Text1));
            resolver.query(uri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME});

}
    });
}
}
```

New code

```
package com.xenom.text;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.PhoneLookup;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class DriveAndTextActivity extends Activity 
{

private Button mbutton1;
private String mText1;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 

    // Obtain handles to UI objects
    mbutton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    mbutton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        private String TAG;

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "mbutton1 clicked");
            Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(mText1));
            resolver.query(uri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME});

}
    });
}
}
```

logcat:

```
[2011-07-27 22:43:56 - ddmlib]An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:574)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHeap.sendREAQ(HandleHeap.java:348)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.requestAllocationStatus(Client.java:420)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:854)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:822)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.processIncomingJdwpData(DeviceMonitor.java:781)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:649)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.access$100(DeviceMonitor.java:42)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$3.run(DeviceMonitor.java:577)

[2011-07-27 22:43:56 - ddmlib]An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:574)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHeap.sendREAQ(HandleHeap.java:348)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.requestAllocationStatus(Client.java:420)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:854)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:822)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.processIncomingJdwpData(DeviceMonitor.java:781)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:649)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.access$100(DeviceMonitor.java:42)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$3.run(DeviceMonitor.java:577)

[2011-07-27 22:43:56 - ddmlib]An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:574)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHeap.sendREAQ(HandleHeap.java:348)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.requestAllocationStatus(Client.java:420)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:854)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:822)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.processIncomingJdwpData(DeviceMonitor.java:781)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:649)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.access$100(DeviceMonitor.java:42)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$3.run(DeviceMonitor.java:577)

[2011-07-27 22:43:56 - ddmlib]An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:574)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHeap.sendREAQ(HandleHeap.java:348)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.requestAllocationStatus(Client.java:420)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:854)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:822)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.processIncomingJdwpData(DeviceMonitor.java:781)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:649)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.access$100(DeviceMonitor.java:42)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$3.run(DeviceMonitor.java:577)

[2011-07-27 22:43:57 - ddmlib]An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:574)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHeap.sendREAQ(HandleHeap.java:348)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.requestAllocationStatus(Client.java:420)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:854)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:822)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:618)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.access$100(DeviceMonitor.java:42)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$3.run(DeviceMonitor.java:577)
```

Comment: Could you please run DDMS and check what logcat has to say about this? As we don't quite know what your error is, we probably (and I say probably just because there actually are people might pull that off on this site) won't be able to help you. Update your original post with a copy from the relevant stacktrace (found in logcat).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't think you posted the relevant logcat-output; could you look for some Exceptions regarding `com.xenom.text`?

Answer (score 1):

Where are you instantiating the `button1` instance? You need something like

`button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.myButton);`

Whats the log say? I am guessing you are getting a `NullPointerException` on the line when you try to set an on click listener on a null variable reference.

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize the button. First, change the global variable, `button1`, into type `Button`. Then, after the setContentView(R.layout.main), call this:

```
button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
```

**UPDATE:**

The error could also be because you are trying to do `Uri.encode(mText1)` even though mText1 is null.